# apt-get update failed a new install of Ubuntu (file has unexpected size, mirror sync in progress)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

OS: macOS Monterey 12.3.1
Hypervisor: Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.34

I have installed latest Ubuntu, however whenever I type in "apt update" this is what happens.

The issue is still present since few months ago, despite reinstalls of the host os.

I have already tried changing the server location to Main, because it used the Polish one by default, to no avail.

I have also tried waiting for the "sync" of the server to finish, also didn't help.

I had to cut the message drastically because of the silly "spam" detector which flagged it for some reason.

```
  File has unexpected size (13203 != 1040312). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:1040312 [weak]
   - SHA256:899066c13d1ea78bfe577b1acb26db3a0641385159c0f1a938ab66b8b30c54f4
   - SHA1:ee465975963ec9e83f95bbaeab3b5c78f7605d87 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:44e5eee449c2602b3b87f014530c38ee [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 +0000

Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (13209 != 6628). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:6628 [weak]
   - SHA256:e55c475ddae586e2ba1768747fc1897b3d1b0cff1f7d945224e8667422db6f5d
   - SHA1:91ae12c7bdf528a0f44b9aebc9c00b7d6a94b18d [weak]
   - MD5Sum:a2b51dc93abfd18616284b0d3d4ffbc7 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 29 Apr 2022 15:46:01 +0000
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2 497 B]
Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons  

Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Fetched 208 kB in 10s (21,5 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/899066c13d1ea78bfe577b1acb26db3a0641385159c0f1a938ab66b8b30c54f4  File has unexpected size (13203 != 1040312). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1040312 [weak]
    - SHA256:899066c13d1ea78bfe577b1acb26db3a0641385159c0f1a938ab66b8b30c54f4
    - SHA1:ee465975963ec9e83f95bbaeab3b5c78f7605d87 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:44e5eee449c2602b3b87f014530c38ee [weak]
   Release file created at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/7bf60e9918f80a7278fd6baf49056aaad676d36d3acf1113561894c3eb98d3de  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/d29cb24c93fec5f43255706bce7eb46d4779952039d8c68ac1bb14a6f3655ce2  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/0ced8b76967dac30c18568f682f0d67744c9255647c4ab184ca4e2e865e39b51  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/69c65ea370877691c8ac9827e89c68d134055f5c6eb569d963c9cac99e94edb8  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/ac3ebc3fdeb01efe2a90baddf426019c34b85fc60fdf4c02db1475396df1a2fd  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/1d7dfbdc732c04cdb452476d2912a2b67e9460e048e8a0c81a65937f624e36d8  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/e55c475ddae586e2ba1768747fc1897b3d1b0cff1f7d945224e8667422db6f5d  File has unexpected size (13209 != 6628). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:6628 [weak]
    - SHA256:e55c475ddae586e2ba1768747fc1897b3d1b0cff1f7d945224e8667422db6f5d
    - SHA1:91ae12c7bdf528a0f44b9aebc9c00b7d6a94b18d [weak]
    - MD5Sum:a2b51dc93abfd18616284b0d3d4ffbc7 [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 29 Apr 2022 15:46:01 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/314b60860225c9197ba68537a79147500c3d8d1d204aa1ba8810e8dd974c0ff3  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/77bd54b14f9f30eda5ecc507066d2ccc7167887108eed1de8dfb424ae2fd1941  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: "mirror sync in progress" should be self-explanatory so try again later or use a different server.

Comment: As I have said in the post, it's likely not about the mirror. I have even explicitly stated - I have tried waiting and changing the mirror. The issue is there since months, despite reinstalls of the OS. Please read my question again.

Comment: Fixed: caused by Screen Time & blocking of adult sites.